# How to update jQuery DropdownChecklist from server-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, client-side, server-side

I'm working on an ASP.Net webpage which will use the jQuery Dropdown Checklist (http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/). I'm fairly inexperienced with JavaScript and completely new to jQuery.

Basically, my question is:  **How do you update the selected items in a jQuery DropdownChecklist from the server-side?**

---

**NOTE:** For details on the solution, scroll to the bottom of the question.

---

Here's some background to give you a better idea of what I'm doing...

I have a jQuery DropdownChecklist which is being populated when the page loads.  When a user selects an item in the DropdownChecklist, the selected values are collected and stored in a hidden input field, then a postback is performed, which allows the server to update a server control.  This part is working.

Now, here's my problem.  This server control, which is actually a usercontrol has a "Remove" button for each selected item in the DropdownChecklist.  When a "Remove" button is clicked, it should cause the associated item in the jQuery DropdownChecklist to be de-selected.  So, far I haven't figured out how to make that happen.

Here's some relevant code snippets:

Here's the markup...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smScriptMgr" runat="server" />
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
               <select id="s1" multiple="true" runat="server" />
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                         <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                         <uc1:SelectedFilterBox ID="sfbFilters" runat="server" Width="200" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
               </asp:UpdatePanel>
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the JavaScript...

```
function DoPostback() {
 __doPostBack('UP1', '');
};

$(function () {
 $("#s1").dropdownchecklist({ forceMultiple: true, width: 200,  textFormatFunction: function() {
        return "Filters:";
        }
 });

 $('#s1').change(function () {
  var values = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("inpHide").value = values;
  DoPostback();
 });
});
```

Here's the markup of the usercontrol...

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SelectedFilterBox.ascx.vb"
    Inherits="SelectedFilterBox.SelectedFilterBox" %>

<div>
    <asp:Table ID="tblFilters" runat="server" Width="200">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpFilters" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table class="selectedFilter">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="selectedFilterLeft">
                                    <%# Eval("filterName")%>
                                </td>
                                <td class="selectedFilterRight" align="right">
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("filterName") %>' OnCommand="ibRemove_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

Here's some relevant portions of the code-behind...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   If Not IsPostBack Then
      'populate dropdown checklist
      s1.Items.Add("Filter A")
      s1.Items.Add("Filter B")
      s1.Items.Add("Filter C")
   Else
      'update filters based on contents of hidden input field
      UpdateFilters(inpHide.Value)
   End If

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateFilters(ByVal filters As String)
   Dim Filter() As String = Split(filters, ",")
   Dim Index As Integer = 0

   'clear existing filters
   sfbFilters.Clear()

   'loop through adding filters based on supplied string
   For Each str As String In Filter
      sfbFilters.Add(str, Index.ToString())
      Index += 1
   Next str
End Sub

'this event occurs when a Remove button is clicked
Protected Sub sfbFilters_FilterChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sfbFilters.FilterChanged
   'update hidden input field
   inpHide.Value = UpdateHiddenField()

   'update label, listing (filter, value) pairs
   UpdateFilterValueSets()
End Sub
```

Here's a JavaScript function that does what I want...

```
function DeselectFilter(targetString){
  $("#s1 option").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() === targetString) $(this).attr("selected", "");
  });
  $("#s1").dropdownchecklist("refresh");
};
```

However, I'm not sure I'm calling it right from the onClientClick event.  Does this look right?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("filterName") %>' OnCommand="ibRemove_Click" OnClientClick='DeselectFilter("<%#Eval("filterName") %>");' />
```

After some back-and-forth in the comments, here's the solution that worked...

```
<a onclick='DeselectFilter("<%#Eval("filterName") %>");'>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ibRemove" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("filterName") %>' OnCommand="ibRemove_Click" />
</a>
```

We determined the simplest solution was to call the JavaScript function from the client-side rather than try to do it from the server-side.  The ImageButton does have an onClientClick event, but for some reason it didn't work.  However, wrapping the ImageButton in a client-side anchor tag and using its onclick event did the charm.

Thank you, [Coding Gorilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228963/coding-gorilla), for all your help.

Comment: Can you clarify: Does each individual item have a "remove" button, or is it a single remove button that should affect each item which is Checked?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes, each selected item in the DropdownCheck list has an associated "remove" button in the usercontrol.  When a "remove" button in the usercontrol is clicked, the associated item in the DropdownChecklist should be de-selected.

Comment: Does it do anything other than deselect it?  That seems a little redundant, why not just uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: Personally, I agree with you, but that is the requirement.

Comment: Yes, the usercontrol's only purpose is to display the items selected in the DropdownChecklist and to allow the user to remove (or de-select) them.

Comment: Ok, so all the button does is uncheck the checkbox (not being critical, I'm trying to understand what your needs are).  So you want to hand the button click event on the server side, and then after the postback when the page is re-rendered the checkbox should be unchecked?  Am I missing anything?

Comment: This will be used to filter data displayed elsewhere on the page.  Basically, the DropdownChecklist contains a list of available filters and the usercontrol shows a list of active filters.

Comment: I added some snippets of the code-behind to my question, if that helps.

Comment: So it would be a lot simpler to handle the button click event via javascript/jquery, is that feasible?

Comment: Hmm... Good idea.  It is in a usercontrol, but I don't think that would be a problem.  I'm not very experienced with javascript/jquery though.  Could you give me an example of a function for de-selecting an item in a dropdownchecklist?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code from your user control so I can see how you're rending it?

Comment: Okay, I added it to my question.  I think if I use the onClientClick event and pass it the filtername that should give the client-side function what it needs.

Comment: You're correct, if you can pass the client id to an onClientClick event then you can remove the selected attribute.  I'm stil having trouble generating an example for you because based on the documentation for the JDCL is based off of <select> tags, and that doesn't look like what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help me.  I agree JDCL's documentation seems to be lacking, or maybe I'm just in need of something obscure.

Comment: Do you have a sample page that I can look at by chance?  I just don't know what you can "de-select" since you're not generating <select> lists, or am I missing something?

Comment: I've added a JavaScript function to my question that I think will do what I need, but I'm not sure I have the syntax right for the onClientClick event.  Would you mind taking a look at that?

Comment: Actually, there is a <select> list (top snippet).

Comment: I've set the <select> list to runat="server" in hopes of being able to control it that way, but I can only populate it when the page loads (pre-postback) --after that, I don't seem to be able to control selections.

Comment: I'm using Firebug to try to debug this.  I have a breakpoint on the DeselectFilter function, but it never hits it when the Remove button is clicked. --I just figured my onClientClick syntax was wrong.

Comment: Change your input button away from an ASP.NET control to a normal HTML element like this: `<input type="image" src="/images/delete.gif" onclick="DeselectFilter(<%#Eval("filterName") %>);" />`.  An ASP.NET image button needs the client side onclick event to fire off the postback.  Since your're not doing anything server side, there's no need to have this as a server control.

Comment: Actually, it does call the ibRemove_Click routine on the server-side, but your idea does work! --the JavaScript function is called and the DropdownChecklist item is de-selected.  I just wonder why it doesn't work when its a server control?

Comment: Okay, I wrapped the server control version of the Remove button in an anchor tag which calls the JavaScript function on its onclick event.  Now the server control works! Woo-hoo!

Comment: Make it back into a server contrl (or make another one) and you'll see that the ASP.NET framework generates _it's own_ onclick="" event.  It needs this to fire the postback event when the user clicks the control.  There are ways around this, but if you don't need to use a server control then its best not to.  So is everything function the way you want now?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Mr. Coding Gorilla.  I couldn't have done it without you.  Be sure to post an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Yes, its doing exactly what I wanted.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So through a long back-and-forth through the comments, the solution turned out to be to move the deselection process to the client side, and use javascript and jquery to deselect the item when an  control is clicked.